# std::sort functor one line

Tags: c++, sorting, line, std, functor

I have declared a functor and made a call so std::sort with that functor as a parameter. Code:

```
struct
{
    bool operator() (const CString& item1, const CString& item2){
        return MyClass::Compare( Order(_T("DESC")), item1, item2);
    }

}Comparer;

std::sort(AllObjects.GetData(), AllObjects.GetData() + AllObjects.GetSize(), Comparer);
```

Simple question: can I do this in one line?

Comment: Just don't reduce the number of lines of your code if it makes it less readable.

Comment: In many cases, reducing the number of lines of code can actually *improve* readability. This is why lambdas were introduced to C++, to remove the clutter of creating a new class and function on a different location, so that one snippet of code can be passed to `std::sort`. The flow of the code is much better when the snippet is provided where `std::sort` is called, which is what `lambda` really accomplishes, rather than a mere reduction in LOC.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: What do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler supports [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you can use a lambda

```
std::sort(AllObjects.GetData(), AllObjects.GetData() + AllObjects.GetSize(),
          [](const CString& item1, const CString& item2) {
              return MyClass::Compare( Order(_T("DESC")), item1, item2);
          });
```

without [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you can simplify it only a little bit by using a function instead of a functor

```
static inline bool Comparer(const CString& item1, const CString& item2) {
    return MyClass::Compare(Order(_T("DESC")), item1, item2);
}
```

and use that as the last parameter.

Unfortunately (?), there are only function wrappers for unary or binary function objects. If there were wrappers for ternary function objects too, you **could** do something similar to

```
std::sort(AllObjects.GetData(), AllObjects.GetData() + AllObjects.GetSize(),
          std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(MyClass::Compare), Order(_T("DESC"))));
```

If you consider using [boost - bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions), you can try this instead

```
std::sort(AllObjects.GetData(), AllObjects.GetData() + AllObjects.GetSize(),
          boost::bind(MyClass::Compare, Order(_T("DESC")), _1, _2));
```

This is equivalent to [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Comment: Thanks very much! And if I my version was previous than C++11, which did not have lambda functionality, what could I do?

Comment: @sergiol I updated my answer a bit. I hope, it solves the remaining issues.

Comment: I really have the luck of Visual C++ 2010 supporting the lambda functionality. Case this was not true, no way that I would add boost to this project only because of a source code line that would appear in only two places! Anyway, thanks for the info.