# Sort entire struct array based on gc value

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

How do i go about sorting the entire struct and all its elements in the array based on `double gc` from lowest to highest?

I have no idea where to begin, and have been struggling for hours.

```
struct DNA
{
    vector <string>header;
    string DNAstrand;
    double gc;
    int valid; // 0 not valid | 1 valid
};
struct World
{
    //  int     numCountries;
    DNA dnas[MAX_DNA_SIZE];
} myWorld;
```

Basically my goal is to arrange all the elements in sync using gc lowest to highest, so if i pull `myWorld.dnas[2].valid` or so itll correlate to its gc once sorted.

Comment: So basically, you want to sort with gc as a key?

Comment: If that is the term yes please. @templatetypedef

Comment: But i am not looking for any complicated tree sorting algo etc. @templatetypedef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to have C++11, you can try the following:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    struct
    {
        bool operator()( DNA const& a, DNA const& b )
        {
            return a.gc < b.gc;
        }
    } dna_comparer;

    std::sort( myWorld.dnas, myWorld.dnas + MAX_DNA_SIZE, dna_comparer );
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I am getting this error now `error: no matching function for call to 'sort(DNA [5000], DNA*, <anonymous struct>&)'|` @user2296177

Comment: I changed it to `static bool dna_comparator(DNA a, DNA b) { return a.gc > b.gc; }` and it seemed to work. Am i on the right path?

Comment: @sonicboom Using `>` will sort them in descending order. Using `DNA` instead of `DNA const&` will entail two copies every time the comparer is called. It will work, however.

Comment: @sonicboom Yes, but please test stuff like that on your own; nobody wants to answer things that can be easily verified by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

That's rather easy with C++11 and `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(myWorld.dnas), std::end(myWorld.dnas), [](const DNA& dna1, const DNA& dna2) { return dna1.gc < dna2.gc; });
```

Comment: I am getting an error as follows `Begin was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Try with `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Comment: Now im getting `begin is not a member of std` @Jack

Comment: Same goes for `end is not a member of std` and im using `namedspace std`

Comment: @sonicboom Try adding `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: Same thing, is it possible my C++ compiler doesnt support it? @user2296177

Comment: @sonicboom Try replacing with `myWorld.dnas` and `myWorld.dnas + MAX_DNA_SIZE` respectively for `begin(...)` and `end(...)`.

Comment: Its the same issue, i went ahead and tried that @user2296177. Im at a loss lol

Comment: I am reading it can be an old GCC version, `Old GCC version

std::begin()  exists in C++11 standard and in GCC 4.7 C++ header files.`

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with anything older than C++11

Comment: Lambdas are a C++11 thing, the original answer states that it is C++11 code. So you'll have to create a functor instead.

Comment: Yeah i just didnt know i wasnt using C++11 till now. @user2296177. So a custom function?

Comment: @sonicboom I've posted an answer that you may try and comment on if it works or doesn't.

Comment: @sonicboom: not a custom function but a functor. An object which wraps and encapsulates a function, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181378/stdsort-functor-one-line